# ¿Cómo unir dos dataframe de pandas sin todas las columnas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Estoy intentando unir dos dataframes de pandas por medio de la función pd.marge, pero de la tabla right no requiero todas las columnas.  Como podría traer solo las columnas necesitas? El siguiente, es el código que estoy utilizando.

```
union = pd.merge(fecha, msft, how='left', on=None, left_on= 'fecha', right_on= 'date_msft',
     left_index=False, right_index=False)
```

Muchas gracias por la ayuda que me puedan brindar.

Comment: Selecciona las columnas en el df que le pasas a merge. Por ejemplo `pd.merge(df1, df2[["nombre", "peso", "fecha"]], ...)`

Comment: Muchas gracias, funciona perfecto.